# something to play a VOB file as a screen saver

Tags: windows, screensaver

back to my touchscreen jukebox question, i thought of another way to do it if the software exists, is there something out there that will play a VOB file as a screen saver?  that would do everything that i need it to do right there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Video Screensaver](http://download.cnet.com/Video-Screensaver/3000-2409_4-10820531.html). It's free and works with any file that Windows Media Player can play ( tried a `.vob` file, played well)